# unable to login to mysql console for non root unix users

Tags: mysql, mysqladmin

My Issues is that when I am logged in as a normal user on unix server and then try to login as MySQL root. It throws below error but when I am logged in as root to unix server and then try to connect to MySQL command line it allows me. I don't understand why is this happening. and how to resolve it. I want connect to MySQL command line with any normal unix user not root always.
-sh-4.2$ mysql -u root -pPASSWORD 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)

-sh-4.2$ su Password: 
[root@hostname]# mysql -u root -pPASSWORD 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor. Commands end with ; or \g. Your MySQL
connection id is 78203 Server version: 5.5.52-log MySQL Community
Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights
reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input
statement.

mysql>

Comment: `SHOW GRANTS FOR root@localhost;`

Comment: mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR root@localhost;
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*6387BE4D4543B920AB5F071F60' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: same grants are there on other servers but I am able to login to MySQL command line on other server as a non-root unix user.